# How to use localized android library

Tags: android, localization, android-library

I want to use a github library [Android about page](https://github.com/jvoyatz/android-about-page) in Greek language.

As i can see the library support Greek. Do i need to set localization in my project? (It will be only in Greek language).

I tried adding values-el folder with strings.xml in Greek inside , and add the Greek strings in my values-->strings.xml with no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="about_contact_us">Επικοινωνήστε μαζί μας</string>
    <string name="about_instagram">Ακολουθήστε μας στο Instagram</string>
    <string name="about_facebook">Κάντε like στην σελίδα μας στο Facebook</string>
    <string name="about_play_store">Αξιολογήστε μας στο Play Store</string>
    <string name="about_youtube">Παρακολουθήστε μας στο YouTube</string>
    <string name="about_twitter">Ακολουθήστε μας στο Twitter</string>
    <string name="about_github">Καντε μας fork στο Github</string>
    <string name="about_website">Επισκεφθείτε την ιστοσελίδα μας</string>
</resources>
```

If i need to set localization, whats the easiest way as its the only thing i need translated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i need to set localization in my project ...

No, you don't.
Greek localized strings just will work fine, you should see them without any additional movements if your device's system language is Greek.